# Object reference not set to an instance of an object when ExecuteScalar function is executed

Tags: sql, c#-4.0, exception, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

This is the definition of my function to execute a query that returns a single string value.

```
public static string ExecuteScalar(DbCommand comm)
{
   String value = "";
 try
 {
   comm.Connection.Open();
   **value = comm.ExecuteScalar().ToString();**//exception occurs here.
 }                                             //It says "Object reference is not set instance of an object"
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
   Console.WriteLine(ex);
 }
 finally
 {
   comm.Connection.Close();
 }
 return value;
}
```

It is executed by a function.

```
public static string selectentries(string id)
{
    string value = "";
    DbCommand comm = GenericDataAccess.CreateCommand();
    comm.CommandText = "SelectEntries";

    DbParameter param = comm.CreateParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@id";
    param.Value = id;
    param.DbType = DbType.String;
    comm.Parameters.Add(param);
    try
    {
        value = GenericDataAccess.ExecuteScalar(comm);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
    return value;
}
```

Stored procedure is a query

```
SELECT name from Credentials where student_id=@id.
```

where name is a varchar(30) in database and @id is a string value passed to the stored procedure.

How to rectify this problem?

Comment: Did you try to debug your code?

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that the following method returned null:

```
comm.ExecuteScalar();
```

Which results in an exception when you try to call .ToString():

```
comm.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

This happens if the query returns no rows.  E.g. because there is no student in the database matching the supplied id.

Comment: I debugged the code and found that the SQL query was the problem, I was applying it on wrong table. I wasn't expecting that the problem would be here.